# Count distinct words (not the total word count)

Tags: microsoft-word

Microsoft Word could count the words in a file, but is there a way to count the distinct words? Even better if it's possible to generate a list of such distinct words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a complete index of all words in a Microsoft Word document, and that can be done with a macro, such as these from [devblogs.Microsoft.com](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-unique-words-used-in-a-microsoft-word-document/) and from [Answers.Microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2013_release/how-to-create-an-index-of-an-entire-text-ie-of-all/2d113f21-6f10-4010-8cc9-ef6f4aeb5eee). Note that some characters, e.g. period (end stop), are counted as words.

The code from devblogs is quoted, below.

```
Set objDictionary = CreateObject(“Scripting.Dictionary”)


Set objWord = CreateObject(“Word.Application”)
objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(“C:\Scripts\Sample.doc”)

Set colWords = objDoc.Words

For Each strWord in colWords
    strWord = LCase(strWord)
    strLetter = Left(strWord, 1)
    If ASC(strLetter) < 97 OR ASC(strLetter) > 122 Then
    Else
        If objDictionary.Exists(strWord) Then
            Else
            objDictionary.Add strWord, StrWord
       End If
    End If
Next

Set objDoc2 = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

For Each strItem in objDictionary.Items
    objSelection.TypeText strItem & vbCrLf
Next

Set objRange = objDoc2.Range
objRange.Sort
```